# Get a RETURN from a Invoke method

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox, invoke

I am trying to read value from a listbox item that is on another thread.

I tried to make a new method to run the invoke command, I can manage to send a command to the listbox like add via the invoke method but i cant seem to get a response, i cant seem to get the value of the item, i have tried a few ways, once i change it from a void to a string things start to get hairy...

```
  thread t1 = new thread(thethread)
    t1.start()

    public void thethread()
    {
    string text = readListBoxSelected(listBox1) + " lala" ;
    }



    public static string readListBoxSelected(ListBox listbox)
    {
        if (listbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            return (string)listbox.Invoke(
              new Func<String>(() => readListBoxSelected(listbox))
            );
        }
        else
        {

            string varText = listbox.SelectedValue.ToString();
            return varText;
        }
        }
```

Above is a example of what i am trying to do.

Here is the error:

> System.NullReferenceException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message=Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>   Source=********   StackTrace:
>          at ********.Form1.readListBoxSelected(ListBox listbox) in e:\documents and
>   settings\scott\my documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects*************\Form1.cs:line
>   133
>          at *******.Form1.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_3()
>   in e:\documents and settings\scott\my
>   documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects**************\Form1.cs:line
>   127   InnerException:

I imagine what is wrong is exactly what it says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"....... All my variables seem to be declared as fair as i am aware, how can i correct this??

I get the feeling i am going about the entire thing wrongly.... 0_o
Thanks in Advance,
Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
public static string readListBoxSelected(ListBox listbox)
    {
        if (listbox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            return (string)listbox.Invoke(
              new Func<String>(() => readListBoxSelected(listbox))
            );
        }
        else
        {
if(istbox.SelectedValue != null)

            return  listbox.SelectedValue.ToString();
else
return String.Empty
        }
        }
```

Comment: hmm thanks for the fix, I cant work out why its returning null, i mean the listbox item is selected via code and it returns null and if i select it with the mouse in the app it still contains null, yet the listbox is full of text.....

Comment: working now thanks both of you guys, problem was i was directly selecting the item, i need to use invoke to select it also....

Comment: do you mean you want to select the item programmatically  not by user click?

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine, the problem seems on the **SelectedValue**, is it **null**. ???

Comment: i agree, may be selectedvalue is null and you are trying to convert it to string

Comment: hmm the selected value is defently not null, for i am selecting it before i click my start button to run the code.

Comment: Hmm i stuck a messagebox.show in tehre to see what was going on, seems it is always returning null... yet the listbox item is selected...]

Comment: listbox is being selected like so:

                int i = 1;
                while(i <= listBox1.Items.Count)
                {


                    listBox1.SelectedItem = i;

Comment: ok i think i got it sorted i need to invoke the listbox to actually select a item also.. from another thread.... was so much easyer when i could just go .....  CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

LOL

Comment: ok it was returning NULL simply because listbox.SelectedValue isnt really the call im after to read the selectedvalue (you would think it was), if i change it to listbox1.text all works fine...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

You where correct, Problem was it was returning a null value..
I was so sure that i was selecting the item correctly i never thought it could be the problem.

Turns out the problem was two things:

**1)
The way i was selecting item, i was using listbox.Selecteditem = 1 , now if i use listbox.setSelected(1,true) all is good :)**

and

**2)
The way i was getting the items text was wrong, listbox.SelectedValue is nothing, it dosnt do what we all imagine it to do... the call i need was listbox.Text .........**

> ```
> public static string readListBoxSelected(ListBox listbox)
> {
>     if (listbox.InvokeRequired)
>     {
>         return (string)listbox.Invoke(
>           new Func<String>(() => readListBoxSelected(listbox))
>         );
>     }
>     else if(listbox.Text != null)
>     {
>         return  listbox.Text.ToString();
>     } 
>     else
>     return String.Empty;
>     }
>
>
> public void selectListBoxItem(ListBox listbox, int num)
> {
>     Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { listbox.SetSelected(num,true); }));
> }
> ```

I must say this is the most anoying thing i have ever done... Everything requires i write a delegate / invoke method for it... Everything... woudlnt something so common be supported by .net on the fly....

Seems a waist of time to write individual delegates for EVERYTHING...

Thanks guys all is working now, yesterday i couldn't foresee me getting to this point,
*Overall problem was Wrong Calls, the invoke was all fine :)*

Scott

EDIT:

**ok it was returning NULL simply because listbox.SelectedValue isnt really the call im after to read the selectedvalue (you would think it was), if i change it to listbox1.text all works fine.... rather silly this .net object oriented stuff if i do say so....**

I must say what a joke... thats kindly destroyed my faith in object oriented programming..
I understand this is not a discussion fourm but honestly the call SelectedValue.toString() should do what we all think it will do.... nope we need to use .Text  to get what we require 0_o.........