# Please i want to know what the differences between these two delegates are?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to use delegate to return combox selected index in c# form. However, when i use the method below it works.

```
 delegate void dttypeDelegate();

object searchType = Invoke(new dttypeDelegate(() =>
           {
              return dbtype.SelectedIndex;

           }));
```

The above method return the combobox selected index to an object searchtype which i m able to retrieve in a form of string. However, the method.

```
delegate int dttypeDelegate();
 private int searchType()
        {
            int i = 0; 
            if (dbtype.InvokeRequired)
            {
                dttypeDelegate dt = new dttypeDelegate(searchType);
                this.Invoke(dt);
            }
            else
            {
                i = dbtype.SelectedIndex; 
            }


          i = dbtype.SelectedIndex; 

           return i;

        }
```

Throws an exception on that  `dbtype.SelectedIndex;` is accessed from the thread other than the method it was made.PLs i wan to know why the exception ? what are the different between the two?

Comment: You access to `dbtype.SelectedIndex` before checking `InvokeRequired`

Comment: I don't think the first code works, because the delegate returns nothing (void), but you wrap a method returning `int` in it, how could it work?

Comment: I though as well before. However it still gives exception after i changed.

Comment: Changed? in what way?

Comment: See the method again. Does it suppose to throw the exception ?

Comment: Now, even if `InvokeRequired` is true, you access it from other thread(last SelectedIndex).

Comment: Terrible question title.

Comment: Sorry . will correct now.

Comment: Yah L.B what you said seems right. IT just that i was not sure how to put it the right way before.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int searchType()
        {
            int i = 0; 
            if (dbtype.InvokeRequired)
            {
                dttypeDelegate dt = new dttypeDelegate(searchType);
                this.Invoke(dt);   // <--- marshal to UI thread
            }
            else
            {
                i = dbtype.SelectedIndex; 
            }


          i = dbtype.SelectedIndex; // <--- now we're back on the non-UI thread.

           return i;
        }
```

You need to exit the method after the `Invoke`.

Comment: I dont understand. What did you changed ?

Comment: I tried the above also and it throws exception. However , i find solution through.

Comment: @NuruSalihu Yes, it also throws the exception because @Dan-o only added comments to describe what is happenning and where. Instead of doing the `i = dbtype.SelectedIndex` again, you need to `return this.Invoke(dt);`.

Comment: Yup . Thats the answer. Thank you . I just saw the correct answer here also.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320250/get-a-return-from-a-invoke-method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers. I saw a similar delegate here that solve my problem . i just need to pass `this.Invoke(dt);` to i first or just return it as a return value.

```
  private int searchType()
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (dbtype.InvokeRequired)
            {

                dttypeDelegate dt = new dttypeDelegate(searchType);
                i = (int)this.Invoke(dt);
                return i;
            }
            else
            {
               return i = dbtype.SelectedIndex; 
            }



        }
```

I saw this in the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320250/get-a-return-from-a-invoke-method)